# VueRouter this.$route.query always empty

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to get the query param `code`, but `$route.query` is always empty. I've used function mode per the docs. What is missing?

**Router:**

```
// use vue-router
import Router from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(Router)

// create router
const router = new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: Home,
      props: (route) => ({ code: route.query.code })
    }
  ]
})
```

**Home.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Navbar />
      <FlatHeader />
      <v-content>
        <ComingSoon />
        <Changes />
        <EmailSubscribe />   
      </v-content>
    <AuthorizationModal />
  </div> 
</template>

<script>
import AuthorizationModal from './components/AuthorizationModal';
import FlatHeader from './components/FlatHeader';
import ComingSoon from './components/ComingSoon';
import Changes from './components/Changes';
import EmailSubscribe from './components/EmailSubscribe';

export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: {
    FlatHeader,
    ComingSoon,
    Changes,
    EmailSubscribe,
    AuthorizationModal
  },
  props: {
    code: {
      type: String,
      default: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$route)
  }
}

</script>
```

**`$route` console output:**

[image]

Comment: You have duplicated name `code` in props and in data

Comment: Show your route path too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I resolved this by setting the mode on `Router` to 'history'.

**Router:**

```
// create router
const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history', // add 'history' mode
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: Home,
      props: (route) => ({ code: route.query.code })
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: This also worked for me, but I'd be very happy to know why.

Answer (score 4):

Stumbled upon similar issue on Vue 3 + Vue Router 4.x with history mode enabled, so the accepted answer didn't fit.

Found a handy `router.isReady()`, which can also solve the problem if you wait for the returned Promise:

```js
<script setup>
onMounted(async () => {
  await router.isReady();
  console.log(router.currentRoute.value);  // all values have been initialized now
});
</script>
```

This worked for me. Quoting related [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/api/interfaces/Router.html#Methods-isReady) for more details:

> `isReady(): Promise<void>`
>
> Returns a Promise that resolves when the router has completed the initial navigation, which means it has resolved all async enter hooks and async components that are associated with the initial route. If the initial navigation already happened, the promise resolves immediately.

PS. In Vue Router 4.x history mode is enabled [this way](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#html5-mode):

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  // ...
})
```